# Minecraft-moding: Mod works only in IDE but not when exported as jar

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

At the moment I'll try to program a simple Minecraft mod which automatically writes a text into a Minecraft `book`.
The Mod works fine when I start Minecraft from the project folder with the help of my IDE(Eclipse).
But when I start Minecraft with the Mod normally without the IDE Minecraft crashes.
And I use `fabric` instead of forge.

I get the following crash Message when I try to join a singelplayer world:

```
MultiMC version: 0.6.7-1375


Minecraft folder is:
G:/Games/MultiMC/instances/1.15.1 fabric - own mod/.minecraft


Java path is:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath/javaw.exe


Java is version 1.8.0_202, using 64-bit architecture.


Main Class:
  net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient

Native path:
  G:/Games/MultiMC/instances/1.15.1 fabric - own mod/natives

Traits:
traits FirstThreadOnMacOS

Mods:
  [✔️] BookFiller-1.0.0-dev
  [✔️] fabric-api-0.4.26+build.283-1.15

Params:
  --username  --version MultiMC5 --gameDir G:/Games/MultiMC/instances/1.15.1 fabric - own mod/.minecraft --assetsDir G:/Games/MultiMC/assets --assetIndex 1.15 --uuid  --accessToken  --userType  --versionType release

Window size: 854 x 480

Java Arguments:
[-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump, -Xms1536m, -Xmx8064m, -Duser.language=en]


Minecraft process ID: 12320


Using onesix launcher.

[20:59:25] [main/INFO]: Loading for game Minecraft 1.15.1
[20:59:28] [main/INFO]: [FabricLoader] Loading 34 mods: minecraft@1.15.1, fabric-renderer-api-v1@0.2.7+f3d8141b95, fabric-networking-blockentity-v0@0.2.3+e08a730595, fabric-keybindings-v0@0.1.1+dfdb52d695, fabricloader@0.7.3+build.176, fabric-renderer-indigo@0.2.21+175d0eb895, fabric-containers-v0@0.1.3+b7f9825d95, fabric-dimensions-v1@0.2.3+06c939b395, fabric-biomes-v1@0.1.5+3b05f68e95, fabric-crash-report-info-v1@0.1.2+b7f9825d95, fabric-events-interaction-v0@0.2.6+12515ed995, fabric-api-base@0.1.2+b7f9825d95, fabric-rendering-v0@1.1.0+5341049095, fabric-rendering-v1@0.1.0+5341049095, fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1@0.1.3+b7f9825d95, fabric-resource-loader-v0@0.1.10+06c939b395, fabric-textures-v0@1.0.4+821cdba795, fabric-content-registries-v0@0.1.3+b7f9825d95, fabric-tag-extensions-v0@0.1.3+abd9158095, fabric-rendering-fluids-v1@0.1.6+12515ed995, fabric-registry-sync-v0@0.2.6+f3d8141b95, fabric-commands-v0@0.1.2+b7f9825d95, fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1@1.1.4+c6a8ea8995, fabric-mining-levels-v0@0.1.1+b7f9825d95, fabric-renderer-registries-v1@2.0.1+5a0f9a6095, fabric-loot-tables-v1@0.1.5+e08a730595, fabric-events-lifecycle-v0@0.1.2+b7f9825d95, bookfiller@1.0.0, fabric@0.4.26+build.283-1.15, fabric-particles-v1@0.1.1+dfdb52d695, fabric-models-v0@0.1.0+dfdb52d695, fabric-item-groups-v0@0.1.6+ec40b2e195, fabric-object-builders-v0@0.1.3+e4c9a9c395, fabric-networking-v0@0.1.7+12515ed995
[20:59:28] [main/INFO]: SpongePowered MIXIN Subsystem Version=0.8 Source=file:/G:/Games/MultiMC/libraries/net/fabricmc/sponge-mixin/0.8+build.17/sponge-mixin-0.8+build.17.jar Service=Knot/Fabric Env=CLIENT
[20:59:30] [main/INFO]: Setting user: Lupos
[20:59:34] [main/INFO]: [Indigo] Registering Indigo renderer!
[20:59:35] [main/INFO]: Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.2 build 10
[20:59:44] [main/INFO]: Narrator library for x64 successfully loaded
[20:59:44] [main/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, Fabric Renderer API (v1), Fabric Networking Block Entity (v0), Fabric Key Bindings (v0), Fabric Renderer - Indigo, Fabric Containers (v0), Fabric Biomes (v1), Fabric Crash Report Info (v1), Fabric Events Interaction (v0), Fabric API Base, Fabric Rendering (v0), Fabric Rendering (v1), Fabric Rendering Data Attachment (v1), Fabric Resource Loader (v0), Fabric Textures (v0), Fabric Content Registries (v0), Fabric Tag Extensions (v0), Fabric Rendering Fluids (v1), Fabric Registry Sync (v0), Fabric Commands (v0), Fabric BlockRenderLayer Registration (v1), Fabric Mining Levels (v0), Fabric Renderer Registries (v1), Fabric Loot Tables (v1), Fabric Events Lifecycle (v0), Book Command Mod, Fabric API, Fabric Models (v0), Fabric Item Groups (v0), Fabric Object Builders (v0), Fabric Networking (v0)
[20:59:53] [main/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[20:59:53] [main/INFO]: Sound engine started
[20:59:53] [main/INFO]: Created: 1024x1024x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/blocks.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 256x128x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/signs.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 1024x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/banner_patterns.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 1024x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shield_patterns.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 256x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/chest.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/beds.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shulker_boxes.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/particles.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/paintings.png-atlas
[20:59:54] [main/INFO]: Created: 256x128x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/mob_effects.png-atlas
[21:00:37] [main/INFO]: [fabric-registry-sync] Loaded registry data [file 1/4]
[21:00:38] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[21:00:38] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[21:00:38] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[21:00:38] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[21:00:38] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[21:00:40] [main/FATAL]: Reported exception thrown!
net.minecraft.class_148: Starting integrated server
    at net.minecraft.class_437.wrapScreenError(class_437.java:452) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1601(class_312.java:86) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_22686(class_312.java:150) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_1255.execute(class_1255.java:94) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_22684(class_312.java:150) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36) ~[lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar:build 10]
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-3.2.2.jar:build 10]
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents(GLFW.java:3101) ~[lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar:build 10]
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.flipFrame(RenderSystem.java:105) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_1041.method_15998(class_1041.java:301) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1523(class_310.java:970) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1514(class_310.java:585) [intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:202) [intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:193) [fabric-loader-0.7.3+build.176.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:138) [fabric-loader-0.7.3+build.176.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:26) [fabric-loader-0.7.3+build.176.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:196) [NewLaunch.jar:?]
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:231) [NewLaunch.jar:?]
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143) [NewLaunch.jar:?]
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34) [NewLaunch.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/nbt/Tag
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.registerCommand(BookCommands.java:33) ~[BookFiller-1.0.0-dev.jar:?]
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.lambda$onInitialize$0(BookCommands.java:25) ~[BookFiller-1.0.0-dev.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.md7edfe3$lambda$addMethods$0$0(class_2170.java:540) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.handler$zee000$addMethods(class_2170.java:540) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.<init>(class_2170.java:218) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_1132.<init>(class_1132.java:52) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1559(class_310.java:1597) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20174(class_528.java:379) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20164(class_528.java:311) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.mouseClicked(class_528.java:257) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_350.mouseClicked(class_350.java:321) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_4069.mouseClicked(class_4069.java:27) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1611(class_312.java:86) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_437.wrapScreenError(class_437.java:447) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.nbt.Tag
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:161) ~[fabric-loader-0.7.3+build.176.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.registerCommand(BookCommands.java:33) ~[BookFiller-1.0.0-dev.jar:?]
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.lambda$onInitialize$0(BookCommands.java:25) ~[BookFiller-1.0.0-dev.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.md7edfe3$lambda$addMethods$0$0(class_2170.java:540) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.handler$zee000$addMethods(class_2170.java:540) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.<init>(class_2170.java:218) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_1132.<init>(class_1132.java:52) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1559(class_310.java:1597) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20174(class_528.java:379) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20164(class_528.java:311) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.mouseClicked(class_528.java:257) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_350.mouseClicked(class_350.java:321) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_4069.mouseClicked(class_4069.java:27) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1611(class_312.java:86) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.class_437.wrapScreenError(class_437.java:447) ~[intermediary-minecraft-1.15.1-client.jar:?]
    ... 27 more
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Uh... Did I do that?

Time: 12/30/19 9:00 PM
Description: Starting integrated server

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/nbt/Tag
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.registerCommand(BookCommands.java:33)
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.lambda$onInitialize$0(BookCommands.java:25)
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.md7edfe3$lambda$addMethods$0$0(class_2170.java:540)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.handler$zee000$addMethods(class_2170.java:540)
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.<init>(class_2170.java:218)
    at net.minecraft.class_1132.<init>(class_1132.java:52)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1559(class_310.java:1597)
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20174(class_528.java:379)
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20164(class_528.java:311)
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.mouseClicked(class_528.java:257)
    at net.minecraft.class_350.mouseClicked(class_350.java:321)
    at net.minecraft.class_4069.mouseClicked(class_4069.java:27)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1611(class_312.java:86)
    at net.minecraft.class_437.wrapScreenError(class_437.java:447)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1601(class_312.java:86)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_22686(class_312.java:150)
    at net.minecraft.class_1255.execute(class_1255.java:94)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_22684(class_312.java:150)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents(GLFW.java:3101)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.flipFrame(RenderSystem.java:105)
    at net.minecraft.class_1041.method_15998(class_1041.java:301)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1523(class_310.java:970)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1514(class_310.java:585)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:193)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:138)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:196)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:231)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.nbt.Tag
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.registerCommand(BookCommands.java:33)
    at com.bookFiller.BookCommands.lambda$onInitialize$0(BookCommands.java:25)
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.md7edfe3$lambda$addMethods$0$0(class_2170.java:540)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.handler$zee000$addMethods(class_2170.java:540)
    at net.minecraft.class_2170.<init>(class_2170.java:218)
    at net.minecraft.class_1132.<init>(class_1132.java:52)

-- Starting integrated server --
Details:
    Level ID: Test
    Level Name: Test
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1559(class_310.java:1597)
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20174(class_528.java:379)
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.method_20164(class_528.java:311)
    at net.minecraft.class_528$class_4272.mouseClicked(class_528.java:257)
    at net.minecraft.class_350.mouseClicked(class_350.java:321)
    at net.minecraft.class_4069.mouseClicked(class_4069.java:27)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1611(class_312.java:86)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.class_526
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.class_437.wrapScreenError(class_437.java:447)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_1601(class_312.java:86)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_22686(class_312.java:150)
    at net.minecraft.class_1255.execute(class_1255.java:94)
    at net.minecraft.class_312.method_22684(class_312.java:150)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents(GLFW.java:3101)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.flipFrame(RenderSystem.java:105)
    at net.minecraft.class_1041.method_15998(class_1041.java:301)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1523(class_310.java:970)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1514(class_310.java:585)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:193)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:138)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:196)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:231)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.15.1
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.15.1
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_202, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 2700449704 bytes (2575 MB) / 4143972352 bytes (3952 MB) up to 7516192768 bytes (7168 MB)
    CPUs: 4
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xms1536m -Xmx8064m
    Fabric Mods: 
        bookfiller: Book Command Mod 1.0.0
        fabric: Fabric API 0.4.26+build.283-1.15
        fabric-api-base: Fabric API Base 0.1.2+b7f9825d95
        fabric-biomes-v1: Fabric Biomes (v1) 0.1.5+3b05f68e95
        fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1: Fabric BlockRenderLayer Registration (v1) 1.1.4+c6a8ea8995
        fabric-commands-v0: Fabric Commands (v0) 0.1.2+b7f9825d95
        fabric-containers-v0: Fabric Containers (v0) 0.1.3+b7f9825d95
        fabric-content-registries-v0: Fabric Content Registries (v0) 0.1.3+b7f9825d95
        fabric-crash-report-info-v1: Fabric Crash Report Info (v1) 0.1.2+b7f9825d95
        fabric-dimensions-v1: fabric-dimensions-v1 0.2.3+06c939b395
        fabric-events-interaction-v0: Fabric Events Interaction (v0) 0.2.6+12515ed995
        fabric-events-lifecycle-v0: Fabric Events Lifecycle (v0) 0.1.2+b7f9825d95
        fabric-item-groups-v0: Fabric Item Groups (v0) 0.1.6+ec40b2e195
        fabric-keybindings-v0: Fabric Key Bindings (v0) 0.1.1+dfdb52d695
        fabric-loot-tables-v1: Fabric Loot Tables (v1) 0.1.5+e08a730595
        fabric-mining-levels-v0: Fabric Mining Levels (v0) 0.1.1+b7f9825d95
        fabric-models-v0: Fabric Models (v0) 0.1.0+dfdb52d695
        fabric-networking-blockentity-v0: Fabric Networking Block Entity (v0) 0.2.3+e08a730595
        fabric-networking-v0: Fabric Networking (v0) 0.1.7+12515ed995
        fabric-object-builders-v0: Fabric Object Builders (v0) 0.1.3+e4c9a9c395
        fabric-particles-v1: fabric-particles-v1 0.1.1+dfdb52d695
        fabric-registry-sync-v0: Fabric Registry Sync (v0) 0.2.6+f3d8141b95
        fabric-renderer-api-v1: Fabric Renderer API (v1) 0.2.7+f3d8141b95
        fabric-renderer-indigo: Fabric Renderer - Indigo 0.2.21+175d0eb895
        fabric-renderer-registries-v1: Fabric Renderer Registries (v1) 2.0.1+5a0f9a6095
        fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1: Fabric Rendering Data Attachment (v1) 0.1.3+b7f9825d95
        fabric-rendering-fluids-v1: Fabric Rendering Fluids (v1) 0.1.6+12515ed995
        fabric-rendering-v0: Fabric Rendering (v0) 1.1.0+5341049095
        fabric-rendering-v1: Fabric Rendering (v1) 0.1.0+5341049095
        fabric-resource-loader-v0: Fabric Resource Loader (v0) 0.1.10+06c939b395
        fabric-tag-extensions-v0: Fabric Tag Extensions (v0) 0.1.3+abd9158095
        fabric-textures-v0: Fabric Textures (v0) 1.0.4+821cdba795
        fabricloader: Fabric Loader 0.7.3+build.176
        minecraft: Minecraft 1.15.1
    Launched Version: MultiMC5
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.2 build 10
    Backend API: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.5.0 NVIDIA 385.54, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using framebuffer using OpenGL 3.0
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fabric'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz
#@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# G:\Games\MultiMC\instances\1.15.1 fabric - own mod\.minecraft\crash-reports\crash-2019-12-30_21.00.40-client.txt
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Process exited with code -1.
```

gradle.properties:

```
# Done to increase the memory available to gradle.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1G

# Fabric Properties
    # check these on https://fabricmc.net/use
    minecraft_version=1.15.1
    yarn_mappings=1.15.1+build.18
    loader_version=0.7.3+build.176

# Mod Properties
    mod_version = 1.0.0
    maven_group = com.book.filler
    archives_base_name = BookFiller

# Dependencies
    # currently not on the main fabric site, check on the maven: https://maven.fabricmc.net/net/fabricmc/fabric-api/fabric-api
    fabric_version=0.4.26+build.283-1.15
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'fabric-loom' version '0.2.6-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

archivesBaseName = project.archives_base_name
version = project.mod_version
group = project.maven_group

minecraft {
}

dependencies {
    //to change the versions see the gradle.properties file
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modCompile "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    // Fabric API. This is technically optional, but you probably want it anyway.
    modCompile "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"

    // PSA: Some older mods, compiled on Loom 0.2.1, might have outdated Maven POMs.
    // You may need to force-disable transitiveness on them.
}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "fabric.mod.json"
        expand "version": project.version
    }

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude "fabric.mod.json"
    }
}

// ensure that the encoding is set to UTF-8, no matter what the system default is
// this fixes some edge cases with special characters not displaying correctly
// see http://yodaconditions.net/blog/fix-for-java-file-encoding-problems-with-gradle.html
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

// Loom will automatically attach sourcesJar to a RemapSourcesJar task and to the "build" task
// if it is present.
// If you remove this task, sources will not be generated.
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = "sources"
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

jar {
    from "LICENSE"
}

// configure the maven publication
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            // add all the jars that should be included when publishing to maven
            artifact(remapJar) {
                builtBy remapJar
            }
            artifact(sourcesJar) {
                builtBy remapSourcesJar
            }
        }
    }

    // select the repositories you want to publish to
    repositories {
        // uncomment to publish to the local maven
        // mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

fabric.mod.json:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 1,
  "id": "bookfiller",
  "version": "${version}",

  "name": "Book Command Mod",
  "description": "This mods allows you to fill books with text!",
  "authors": [
    "Lupos"
  ],
  "contact": {
    "homepage": "https://fabricmc.net/",
    "sources": ""
  },

  "license": "MIT",
  "icon": "assets/modid/communism-icon.png",

  "environment": "*",
  "entrypoints": {
    "main": [
      "com.bookFiller.BookCommands"
    ]
  },
  
  "depends": {
    "fabricloader": ">=0.7.2",
    "fabric": "*",
    "minecraft": "1.15.x"
  },
  "suggests": {
    "flamingo": "*"
  }
}
```

Thats my folder structure:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are developing your mod in an environment with a deobfuscated Minecraft server dependency, and that you are not re-obfuscating references to Minecraft classes in your code (hence the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/nbt/Tag`). Usually, such a re-obfuscation is automatically set-up in any example mod project supplied by the modded server software community, so you can simply copy it from there. It's also possible that you didn't use Gradle at all, but used something like Eclipse export instead. That simply won't work because it skips this re-obfuscation task.

To build your mod on Windows, open cmd.exe in the mod's directory and run `gradlew build`.

Comment: I used `gradlew build` for building the jar. But it didnt work.

Comment: Can you include the `build.gradle` file in your question? This is likely where the issue comes from.

Comment: @Lupos Are you using reflection at all?

Comment: I do not know what you mean with "reflection". So I guess I don't use it.

Comment: Reflection is everything in the `java.lang.reflect` package.

Comment: I do not use any classes from `java.lang.reflect`.

Comment: There is also a Forge provided class, `ReflectionHelper` (or renamed as `ReflectionObfuscationHandler` in more recent version, or something along those lines) which is a wrapper around `java.lang.reflect` methods to make development easier (but is still reflection). If not using that either, it is unclear from what you've posted @Lupos what the problem is.